# Using Behat 2.0, Where should i put my steps?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, bdd, behavior, dml

```
You can implement step definitions for undefined steps with these snippets:

/**
 * @Given /^people enter (\d+)$/
 */
public function peopleEnter($argument1)
{
    throw new Pending();
}
```

Should I put it under bootstrap.php? I'm really confused what should I do know...
I want to use the oop style, not closures.
I'm new to BDD and Behat.
Any help is welcome.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, put it in the Bootstrap.  By default, Behat looks for `bootstrap/FeatureContext.php` as its bootstrap file, but these methods should go into whatever bootstrap class you're using that extends `BehatContext`.